# How can I replace rectangles with images/assets using Jetpack Compose [Kotlin]?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently developing a Sokoban game in Kotlin for an Android app and at this point I have an algorithm that generates a matrix of strings where each string refers to a specific game element, e.g., "#" - Wall, "0" - Floor, "@" - Player, "$" - Box, etc...

Based on that matrix, I am using Jetpack Compose to draw in a canvas rectangles with different colors so I can distinguish the elements (wall, floor, ...) of the Sokoban game.

At the moment, this is the result:

[Elements represented by rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9HV6.png)

However, my final goal is to replace that colored rectangles, with images (.png files). Example:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBWNK.png)

How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
class SokobanActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mGameMatrix: Array<Array<String>>

...

@Composable
fun GameCanvas() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        drawRect(color = Color.Black)
        val squareDim = 64.dp.value
        (mGameMatrix.indices).forEach { i ->
            (mGameMatrix[i].indices).forEach { j ->
                val element = mGameMatrix[i][j]
                drawGameElement(
                    squareColor = when (element) {
                        //Wall
                        "#" -> Color.Red
                        //Floor
                        "0" -> Color.Cyan
                        //Box
                        "$" -> Color.Green
                        //Box-objective
                        "." -> Color.Yellow
                        //Player
                        "@" -> Color.Magenta
                        else -> Color.Blue
                    },
                    Offset(
                        (i * squareDim) + ((size.width - (mGameMatrix.size * squareDim)) / 2),
                        (j * squareDim) + ((size.height - (mGameMatrix.size * squareDim)) / 2)
                    ),
                    size = Size(
                        width = squareDim,
                        height = squareDim
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun DrawScope.drawGameElement(
    squareColor: Color,
    offset: Offset,
    size: Size,
) {
    drawRect(
        color = squareColor,
        topLeft = offset,
        size = size
    )
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just draw your vector, png etc. resources on Canvas, like that:

```
            val image = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = iconRes)
            val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = image)
            translate(
                left = size.width / 2 - painter.intrinsicSize.width / 2,
                top = size.height / 2 - painter.intrinsicSize.height / 2
            ) {
                with(painter) {
                    draw(painter.intrinsicSize)
                }
            }
```